# Alternative to the command "for"

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I created a function with the simple goal of generating a new column in data.frame mixing predicted values (in the absence of actual values) with the actual values. But when I apply this function in my data set, which is huge for a sign (1070125 obs.), the function took a long time to complete your goal (30 minutes).
This is the function:

```
p <- function(object, newdata = NULL, type = c("link", "response", "terms"),
       rse.fit = FALSE, dispersion = NULL, terms = NULL,
       na.action = na.pass, ...) { 
  pred <- predict (object,newdata)
  vetor1 <- newdata$ALT
  vetor1[is.na(vetor1)] <- 0
  vetor2 <- pred
  for (i in 1:length(vetor1)) {
    if (vetor1[i]==0.00) {
      vetor1[i]=vetor2[i]
      newdata$ALTMISTA <- vetor1
    }
  }
return (newdata)
}
```

Could someone show me an alternative? Thank you.

---

Sorry, I typed the code incorrectly.
This is the code in its reproducibly.

```
p <- 
  function(object, newdata = NULL, type = c("link", "response", "terms"),
           rse.fit = FALSE, dispersion = NULL, terms = NULL,
           na.action = na.pass, ...)
  { 
{
    pred <- predict (object,newdata)

      }

    vetor1 <- (newdata$ALT)
vetor1[is.na(vetor1)] <- 0
    vetor2 <- c(pred)
    for(i in 1:length(vetor1)){
      if(vetor1[i]==0.00){
        vetor1[i]=vetor2[i]
        newdata$ALTMISTA <- vetor1
      }
    }
    return (newdata)
  }
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `vetor1 <- ($ newdata ALT)` I ask because it is not a valid `R` construct.

Comment: I think you could replace the for loop with `vetor1 <- ifelse(vetor1 == 0, vector2, vector1)` but it would be easier to tell if you make a reproducible example

Comment: @rawr:  Beware of endorsing use of  "==" with numeric vectors. Unless you and they have read R FAQ 7.31 and understand it fully, you should be using `all.equal` or equivalent.

Comment: good point. @MarianeBiavatti did you hear that?

Comment: @BondedDust  Can I put a plug in for my `cgwtools::approxeq` function here?  It often provides more useable output than `all.equal` or `identical` .

Comment: Mariane: have you checked to see how long the line `pred <- predict (object, newdata)` takes?  My bet is that's the time hog here, not the simple loop (which could easily be vectorized)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I agree that `all.equal` sometimes creates further problems when it doesn't return TRUE. If I remember correctly, one needs to wrap it in some combination of isTRUE and something else that I always need to look up. So it would be nice to have a safe method of testing for near numerical equality other than constructing it from scratch with `abs(x-y) < 1e-10`.

Comment: Mariane, you can delete your answer, I edited the original code to show your update and re-formatted for readability.  You had some unnecessary braces and parens in there too.  Now people will be better able to help you.  The author can always edit the original question too.

Comment: Is `ALT` a shortened version of `ALTMISTA`?  If so, please edit the original question to make them both `ALTMISTA` for clarity.  And to be clear, you are trying to take `newdata$ALT` and modify it, then put it back into `newdata$ALT`?

Comment: @BondedDust my `approxeq` is basically a wrapper, with "treats" :-), of `abs(x-y)<-something_small`